# How builtin function "append" works: appending to a slice whose elements are of type interface

Tags: go

The section of [appending to slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices) on the specification, mentions the following example:

```
var t []interface{}
t = append(t, 42, 3.1415, "foo")   // t == []interface{}{42, 3.1415, "foo"}
```

I'm confused here, why can we append values of `int`, `float` and `string` to a `slice` whose elements are of `interface` type? And why is the result of the `append` like that? I tried hard/long, but I don't get it.

Comment: The slice elements are of type `interface{}` and the braces are not just decoration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because:

> all types implement the empty interface

For details read over the [ref spec for interfaces](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types).

`interface` is similar to `Object` in java where all types/classes/etc are also an `Object`.

You can see this effect [by using `reflect`](https://play.golang.org/p/tIEa7dxI_YE):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var t []interface{}
    z := append(t, "asdf", 1, 2.0)
    fmt.Println(z)

    for i := range z {
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(z[i]))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[asdf 1 2]
string
int
float64
```

Why is it like this? Well, think about serialization especially of [JSON objects](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal); the types can be string, int, object, etc. This allows for deserialization without specifying a fully mapped struct (maybe you don't care and want only some of the data, etc). Basically, it allows you to have a form of "weak typing" in Go; while still being able to have strong typing.

As mentioned below, `reflect` identifies the type for you. When programming though, you may have to do it [manually](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions).

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the "result of append" is not what you see printed.  That is just the string representation, which Asserts the underlying type of the actual value!  If that type assertion weren't made, the slice would look like `[interface{} interface{} interface{}]`

Comment: @threeve, a nitpick: not really asserts but grabs the type directly using the other means of the `reflect` package. It first asserts whether the value's type implements `Stringer` or `error` interfaces, in which case `String` or `Error` methods are called to make the value format itself as a string, respectively.